# Building Spring Cloud Config server with Native files

Tags: maven, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I want to build/deploy the Spring cloud config server in such a way that, when I deploy the config server, it should copy all the properties for the particular profile on some directory path.

Do we have any particular maven plugin for the same?

Comment: Config server doesn't have maven plugins, but it does have a native file mode, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: How to copy files in resources folder to server in some particular location?